# How to show mysql column using conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table name tbl_branch:

```
br_id, br_name, br_loc, br_status, br_more, br_assco

br_id = Int
br_name varchar
br_loc varchar
br_status=varchar
br_more = varchar // value 0 or 1
br_assco = varchar // value 12,14,26,1,10,23
```

I want to show `br_more` and `br_assco` result in query if br_more value is zero. Otherwisw it will show `br_id, br_name, br_loc, br_status` only. can any one give me soln.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show `br_more` and `br_assco` result in query if `br_more` value is zero. Otherwisw it will show `br_id`, `br_name`, `br_loc`, `br_status` only. can any one give me soln.

so show conditional expr for `br_more` value is zero may be soln

```
SELECT t.br_id
     , t.br_name
     , t.br_loc
     , t.br_status
     , IF(t.br_more='0',t.br_more,'')
     , IF(t.br_more='0',t.br_assco,'')
  FROM mytable t
```

---

**EDIT**

RE: "*not working spencer*"

It's working for me. Test case.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( br_id     INT
, br_name   VARCHAR(7)
, br_loc    VARCHAR(6)
, br_status VARCHAR(9)
, br_more   VARCHAR(1)
, br_assco  VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (0,'0','0','0','0','12,14,26,1,10,23') ;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,'1','1','1','1','12,14,26,1,10,23') ;
```

Query returns:

```
 br_id  br_name  br_loc  br_status  IF(t.br_more='0',t.br_more,'')  IF(t.br_more='0',t.b 
------  -------  ------  ---------  ------------------------------  ----------------------
     0  0        0       0          0                               12,14,26,1,10,23
     1  1        1       1
```

Comment: If you can provide an actual specification, like an example of the resultset to be returned, someone maybe able to help you. The example "soln" provided in this answer satisfies the rather vague specification.

Comment: After execute query I encode it to JSON Data:

Comment: [store_id] => 11
            [distance] => 378.145290
            [banner] => data/boutiques/btq1.jpg
            [landmark] => Apeejay House
            [pincode] => 123456
            [owner_name] => Test
            [opening_time] => 
            [closing_time] => 
            [working_time_table] => 
            [remarks] => Free Text here
            [is_more_branch] => 
            [associated_branch] =>

Comment: if [is_more_branch] colmn in database is (0) it will return [is_more_branch] and [associated_branch] column otherwise it will end on [remarks]

Comment: And I use code as u suggest: IF(ows.is_more_branch='0',ows.is_more_branch,'0') AS is_more_branch,
IF(ows.is_more_branch='0',ows.associated_branch,'0') AS associated_branch

Answer (score 0):

conditional select : use case to check for various conditions

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, 
CASE WHEN col_3 = 0 THEN col_3
ELSE CASE WHEN col_3 = 1 THEN col_4 
ELSE col_6 END
END AS
FROM tbl;
```

Example

if col_3 value = 0 the put 0

else put the value of col 4 i.e 24,25

Comment: I am confuse on your sample plz use my sample data

Comment: actual i do not want to print the br_more, br_assco if br_more value is 1

Comment: it's a dummy code, mke the changes as per your requirement